# How to calculate lines by group in linux file

Tags: linux, bash

How to calculate lines following every "group"?

**File:**

```
group
1
2
3
group
1
2
group
1
2
3
4
5
```

**Output:**

```
3
2
5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk 'count && /group/{print count;count="";next} NF && !/group/{count++} END{print count}'   Input_file
```

Comment: console output: -bash: !/group/{count++}: event not found

Comment: It is working well and fine for me, how you are running it, either in script or terminal command we need not to add #!(shebang) in it. Also please mention your OS too, also on a Solaris/SunOS system, change awk to /usr/xpg4/bin/awk , /usr/xpg6/bin/awk , or nawk.

Comment: It works fine now. I added additional ' because of wrong spelling. OS version: CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511